ssh connect to host: Connection timed out
I cannot connect anymore on my system using ssh on Ubuntu 24.04
The port Forwarding (on my ISP router) is ok (see the image) - with these settings was working on 22.04

In my /etc/ssh/sshd_config i have set the port:
Port 2406


The ufw is allowing the port 2406/tcp
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
2406/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
2406/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)   

The ssh server is up and running:
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-11-20 20:19:06 EET; 1min 4s ago
TriggeredBy: ● ssh.socket
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
   Main PID: 7330 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 19006)
     Memory: 2.1M (peak: 2.4M)
        CPU: 19ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─7330 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"

Nov 20 20:19:06 dev-machine systemd[1]: Starting ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Nov 20 20:19:06 dev-machine sshd[7330]: Server listening on :: port 2406.
Nov 20 20:19:06 dev-machine systemd[1]: Started ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server.

When trying to copy some file from another computer to my ssh server:
scp -P 2406 uploaded.tar.gz ubuntu@w.x.y.z:/home/ubuntu/VPS

where w.x.y.z is my public ip address, I receive an error:
ssh: connect to host w.x.y.z port 2406: Connection timed out
lost connection

What I am doing wrong??? The same thing I was doing when having ubuntu 22.04 and worked. After I upgraded to 24.04 (fresh install) - it seems it does not work anymore.
Any ideas?
UPDATE 1
Forgot to mention that my internal IP is static:
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 192.168.1.24  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255

UPDATE 2
The problem is now fixed. The settings were correct. The problem was with my ISP.

you're sure your internal IP is still the same right?  you didn't specify if the internal IP of your system was static or not.  You also don't state if your ISP blocks SSH traffic

@ThomasWard i have updated....it is static and the one that si conf in the router .24

Are you able to ssh from the server to localhost on the configured port? Are you able to ssh to the servers IP, 192.168.1.24, on the configured port from another host on your network?

I don't think I understood you question...I don't have any other device on the same network to test....

I'm trying to figure out if your system is configured properly and allows SSH connections locally before we test from outside the network. So first test on the server itself: ssh localhost -p 2406. Then test on the subnet from another host: ssh 192.168.1.24 -p 2406. Then test externally.

@mpboden yes is working with ssh localhost -p 2406

@steeldriver I'm not sure if the port still needs to be configured in /etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d anymore. According to this post on Discourse, it can be configured as usual in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

If you can connect locally, then the SSH server is configured correctly. So test on subnet to determine if network and server's firewall are configured correctly. If so, and you can't connect externally, then issue is with your router/firewall or your ISP.

that's strange....because on the same day I was able to connect on 22.04 ... then after reinstall the system (upgraded to 24.04) - is no working anymore :|

@mpboden ah OK - I will delete my comment

Did you already try: ssh -v -p 2406 

Note the OP's comment: 'The problem is now fixed. The settings were correct. The problem was with my ISP.' Closed...

You server appears to be configured correctly. The output of systemctl status ssh indicates that it's active and listening on port 2406. Also, your UFW rules are allowing traffic on port 2406.
However, Connection timed out errors typically mean that the SSH client is not seeing any responses from the server. This indicates that the TCP handshake isn't completing and points to something other than SSH being the problem.
To test:
Check your server locally:
ssh localhost -p 2406

If this is successful, test from another host on the network:
ssh 192.168.1.24 -p 2406

If this works, test from an external host.
If an external host doesn't work, inspect your router.
Looking at the screenshot of your port forwarding rules, it appears that the rule isn't enabled. Also, I don't see a public IP address entered, but I'm presuming you omitted that for privacy reasons.


And if that still doesn't help, try tcpdump to check whether there are any packets arriving at all.

I have updated the image ... that checkbox is for selecting and delete the rule. I have tested with another PC from the same network and worked...so the problem is the exterior. I have to contact my ISP and see what they change ... in this short period of time.

Firstly I would test open ports of your traget from client with nmap.
nmap -sV -p- <target ipv4>

If you cant see your ssh service in output something is wrong with your port forwarding or with your firewall.
To eliminate firewall as reason turn it off and run nmap again. If that does not help at all something must be wrong with your port forwarding.
